# Bitcoin Core keeps crashing

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have Bitcoin Core v0.11.0 installed on a machine that's running Windows XP.  After waiting several days to completely synchronize, I decided to update the bincoin.conf file.  I didn't see one where it was supposed to be, so I created a new file that had nothing but the following line it it.

txindex = 1

I saved the file in the appropriate directory and restarted Bitcoin.  Upon starting, it basically said that I had to start synchronizing from scratch (it said I was over 6 years behind).  It then crashed.

Finally, I decided to get things back to the way they were before.  I simply deleted the bitcoin.conf file that I had created, thinking that everything would go back to normal.  It didn't.  Now the program crashes every time I try to start it.  A window pops up that says

"Bitcoin Core (GUI node for Bitcoin) has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience."

So what do I do now?  How do I get Bitcoin Core to stop crashing?

Thanks for your time.

%%%% UPDATE %%%%%%%%%%

As for the debug log, the first line to show an error is the following:

2015-10-30 02:56:56 Error: Couldn't open socket for incoming connections (socket returned error An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used.  (10047))

I've tried saving the bitcoin folder (the one that has the huge blockchain) as a backup and then re-installing The entire program.  After re-installation, if I let it create its own new "Bitcoin" folder, everything is fine.  Then when I try to put the blockchain folders inside the bitcoin folder, that it created, I get the error message.

I hope re-installation wasn't a mistake.  I have the blockchain.  I'd hate to have to re-acquire the whole thing again.

Either way, I really appreciate your speedy responses.  That's excellent!

Comment: Bug reports go to https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues

Comment: When you enable txindex it has to create that index by going through the entire history starting 6 years ago. So at least that part makes sense.

Comment: Can you post the last few lines of debug.log after a crash to find out what it's barfing on?

Comment: As for the debug log, the first line to show an error is the following:

2015-10-30 02:56:56 Error: Couldn't open socket for incoming connections (socket returned error An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used. (10047))

Answer (score -1):

I used to work at Microsoft - testing code - good luck with that - you will likely NEVER get it stable as to the machine you described - it is just too CPU and swap intensive because the XP platform cannot handle the memory the program will actually need and the hard drive - assuming you are NOT running SSD hardware - will never hold up for long

Comment: While this may be sound advice, it doesn't really answer the question about what's causing the crash in this specific case :)